# What is the distance between $\tau=(1,1.,..)$ and $c_0$?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

By definition, $d(\tau,c_0)=\inf\{||\tau-\eta||:\eta\in c_0\}$, but I can't seem to prove that it is 0 or 1.

Clearly, if $\eta=(0,0,...)$, then $d(\tau,\eta)=\inf\{1\}=1$, so $d=d(\tau,\eta)\leq1$. My intuition is it has to be 1, but I have only arrived at $d=\inf\{\sup\{|1-\eta_n|:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\}\}$ with $\lim_{n\to\infty} {\eta_n}=0$. Maybe it is obvious that $\sup\{|1-\eta_n|:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\}\geq 1$, but I don't fully get it.

Comment: Please provide more context. What norms do you consider on which spaces?

Comment: Sorry. $c_o\subset l_{\infty}$, and $\tau\in l_{\infty}$ so basically $||.||_{\infty}$ everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\eta \in c_0$ then for all $\varepsilon\in\mathbb R$ there exists some $n\in \mathbb N$ with $\eta_n\leq\varepsilon$ and thus $\lVert \tau - \eta \rVert_\infty \geq 1-\varepsilon$. Thus we conclude that $\lVert \tau - \eta \rVert_\infty \geq 1$ and therefore
$$
d(\tau,c_0)\geq 1.
$$
But $0\in c_0$ and $\lVert \tau - 0 \rVert_\infty = 1$ so that finally $d(\tau,c_0)\leq1$.